# How to load Interlis1 files directly into QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour 64Bit (W7Pro)

Tags: qgis, ogr, interlis

With earlier version of QGIS (1.8) it was possible to load data in Interlis 1 format directly.

If I try now it says something like unknown format. Is this because I'm using the 64Bit version of the installer?

A possible workaround could be using the examples at http://giswiki.hsr.ch/HowTo_OGR2OGR "interlis to shp".

It would be very nice to be able to open Interlis Files directly again.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're on 64-bit Windows but it is not the only one ... (Linux 64 bits, Mac OS X 64 bits)

On Linux or Mac OS X 64 bits, no problem:

[image]

It depends on the installed version of GDAL/OGR